# CRUD/Admin panel solution for Next.js app

Tags: typescript, next.js, content-management-system, crud, vercel

I have a Next.js typescript app which is mostly static site with some bells and whistles (i.e. i18n, mailing lists and so on). Happily spinning on vercel.
I’m using tRPC wherever possible and would like to keep it that way.

Now we need a solution to let unqualified personnel to change some texts, upload files, update blog posts etc.

I’m considering writing some kind of CRUD app and protecting it with Clerk.com auth. This lets me to keep on using tRPC and be flexible about what and where I can edit. But of course requires plenty of boilerplate code, database planning etc.

What's the easiest/cheapest way to accomplish the goal while keeping things fast and simple? Some kind of headless cms or CRUD plugin maybe?

Comment: You should let them have access to the CMS at the end of the day. Your CMS of choice (Sanity, Dato, etc.) should have the controls needed for constraints and role permissions. Is that an option?

Comment: Sure, I’m just dreaming of something super light and easy-to-set-up. More of CRUD-gen than full fat CMS if you know what mean